# TeamCity - problem reading text from same file a second time

Tags: cmd, teamcity

I'm seeing some peculiar behaviour in a TeamCity step that uses a cmd script.

In the example below, %USERPROFILE%\myfile.txt contains only the text "abc123" without quotes.

```
set /p myFileContent=<"%env.USERPROFILE%\myfile.txt"
echo "%%myFileContent%%"
set /p myFileContentTwo=<"%env.USERPROFILE%\myfile.txt"
echo "%%myFileContentTwo%%"
```

Output:

```
"abc123"
""
```

What is going on here? The file is read correctly first time, but not the second time. It works fine if I run the equivalent cmd script outside of TeamCity:

```
@echo off
set /p myFileContent=<"%USERPROFILE%\myfile.txt"
echo "%myFileContent%"
set /p myFileContentTwo=<"%USERPROFILE%\myfile.txt"
echo "%myFileContentTwo%"
```

Output:

```
"abc123"
"abc123"
```

I first observed this problem when reading the same file in two separate steps, with a wait of several seconds between reads, suggesting it's not a sharing violation. The file is intact and has the expected content after all steps have run.

I'm on TeamCity Enterprise 2021.2.1 (build 99602) on Windows 10.

Comment: replace each `%%` with `%`.

Comment: @Stephan - can you explain the rationale behind the single %? If %% is wrong, why does it work the first time?  In TeamCity, the extra % is needed to expand a variable, hence %% when expanding a (nested) cmd variable.

Comment: I have no clue about teamcity. But if it needs `%%` , why doesn't it need them with `set /p` or `echo "%env.USERPROFILE%\myfile.txt"`?

Comment: And what do you mean with "nested variable"? Do you need the value of `%abc123%`?

Comment: The % ones are TeamCity parameters - only a single % is needed to expand them correctly. The %% (as far as I understand) is needed for the "double" expansion of cmd within TC.

Comment: Only thing I can imagine is, that `myFileContent` is predefined for any reason.

Comment: As an experiment I added myFileContent and myFileContentTwo as TeamCity parameters, to allow the use of a single %. Alas, it still doesn't work. I can't reproduce it in a cut-down project which hints at something environmental, e.g. permissions or antivirus.